# Accessing dynamically created checkbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, checkbox

I am creating a few checkboxes when I open a form with the following code:

```
    private void OpenFolder_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        foreach (string file in filesToOpen)
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
            lbl.Width = 200;
            lbl.Height = 25;
            lbl.AutoEllipsis = true;
            lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 40 + 25 * i);

            this.Controls.Add(lbl);

            string checkName = "check" + i;
            CheckBox check = new CheckBox();
            check.Checked = true;
            check.AccessibleName = checkName;
            check.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(340, 40 + 25 * i);
            check.CheckedChanged +=new EventHandler(check_CheckedChanged);

            this.Controls.Add(check);

            CheckBoxes.Add(check);

            i++;
        }
```

and I am trying to check the state of the checkboxes everytime one changes to toggle my OK button (the user can validate only if there are a certain number of the checkboxes checked)

here is the code I use, but it fails as I am not able to target the checkboxes:

```
    private void check_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < filesToOpen.Count(); i++)
        {
            string tbarName = "tbar" + i;
            string checkName = "check" + i;

            CheckBox ckb = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                     .Where(c => c.AccessibleName.Equals(checkName)) as CheckBox;
            TrackBar tkb = this.Controls.OfType<TrackBar>()
                     .Where(t => t.AccessibleName.Equals(tbarName)) as TrackBar;
            //TrackBar tkb = this.Controls.Find(tbarName, false).First() as TrackBar;
            //CheckBox ckb = this.Controls.Find(checkName, false).First() as CheckBox;

            if (ckb.Checked == true)
            {
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
```

what am I doing wrong/really wrong?

Comment: I get a nullreferenceexception because there is nothing in ckb

Comment: Why don't you use the property 'name' of the control instead of 'accessibleName' . If I don't remember wrong doing so you may be able to access them by 'this.Controls[checkName]'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you add the checkboxes to your own list:

```
CheckBoxes.Add(check);
```

it would be simpler to loop over that rather than trying to find the control associated with the file:

```
foreach (var checkBox in CheckBoxes)
{
    if (checkbox.Checked)
    {
        // Do stuff...
    }
}
```

However, you shouldn't need to use a separate list. This line is wrong:

```
CheckBox ckb = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                   .Where(c => c.AccessibleName.Equals(checkName)) as CheckBox;
```

`Where` returns a `IEnumerable<CheckBox>` but you are trying to cast it directly to a `CheckBox` which will return `null`. What you should have is:

```
CheckBox ckb = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()
                   .Where(c => c.AccessibleName.Equals(checkName)).First();
```

You will still need to check to see if `ckb` is null (just in case there is nothing on the list) but this should return you the control you are looking for.

Comment: `CheckBoxes.Add(check);` is a remnant from a try, I didnt succeed in adding the checkboxes to the list in fact... I get a nullreferenceexception when trying to add anything

Comment: @ThomasC - have you initialised `CheckBoxes`?

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of "this" and then check its Controls collection - your checkboxes are probably a few iterations down the tree.

You'd need some kind of recursive find controls function such as the one found [in this article](http://intrepidnoodle.com/articles/24.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all the checkboxes with every check is not required and is readlly hard processing work. Instead when creating you always know in what state you've created those - so just keep the count of "Checked" checkboxes. When a checkbox being checked increment the count, and when one unchecked - take out 1 from the count. And later have a check: "if (count == requiredCount) {//Logic here}"
So the code will look like:

```
private int checkedCount;
private void check_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
  this.checkedCount += (sender as CheckBox).Checked?1:-1;
  if(this.checkedCount == requiredCount)
  { 
    //do stuff 
  } 
}
```

Good luck with development.