# display text on empty tab control in c#

Tags: c#, label, tabcontrol

I have 2 tab controls in a split container, and I would like to display some text ("1" for the left one and "2" for the right one) when there are no tabs opened. is there a way to do so?

Comment: could you pls give us some more details? where do you want do display the text? What dou you mean with "no tabs opened" a tab control always shows a/one tab - perhaps some code/screens may be useful. thx

Comment: I'd say dynamically create a label control, like you have done [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735722/accessing-dynamically-created-checkbox-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @PilgerstorferFranz I cant post images yet unfortunatly... the tabcontrols are used to display datagrids, but as long as the user does not open anything, they are empty. The text should be where the tabs are going to be displayed (therefore hidden when the first tab is opened)

Comment: @JeremyThompson this would be fine, but where should I put the label? I cant put it in the tabcontrol without adding a tab, and thats not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab == null)
        lblMessage.Text = "1";
    else
        lblMessage.Text = "";
}
```

Look at the Image, I set the `tabControl2.SelectedTab = null;` in the button22 click

[image]

Comment: thanks for the snippet, but the problem is to display the label, VS wont let me add it to the tabcontrol (says only tabs can be added to it)

Comment: you should not add it to the tab control, add it  to the split container, and then set it's left and height properties, hide it when some tab is selected

Answer (score 0):

Tab control is a container control so you can add label control on tab control and display desired text. When you load first tab page in tab control cust hide label or empty it's content.

Comment: How can I add the label to the tabcontrol? VS says I can only had tabs to it